# Como sacar una variable de una función automática jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery

He intentado implementar una función JQuery para poder obtener las direcciones href que genero en un for. Es la primera vez que utilizo jQuery y no se como funciona. Mi problema esta en que no se como obtener la alerta que genero. Es decir como llamar a la función para igualarla a una variable o simplemente llamarla y que la función haga un return.

Este seria el código:

```
<script>
        $(a.ejercicio).each(function( index, element ) {
             $(this).click(function {
                 return ($(this).attr("href"))
             })      
         });
</script>
```

Me gustaría saber si se puede obtener una variable que contenga lo que devuelve este código en cualquier parte de mi documento, es decir,
me gustaria poder hacer esto: Variable direccion=funcionjQuery.

Comment: antes que nada, cambia el id del div, no puede tener espacios, ni empezar por numero

Comment: simplemente quita el alert del return, y te devolvera el resultado

Comment: Y como se llama? como lo pongo dentro del id del div para que me lo reconozca como id

Comment: por ejemplo id="miDiv"

Comment: vaya alarde de imaginacion que acabo de demostrar

Comment: quitamos el `alert` del `return` y te devolverá el valor que deseas.

Comment: por otro lado, no veo que sacas con que te devuelca el valor. Que es lo que pretendes que ocurra exactamente?

Comment: una vez obtenida la dirección del href puedo hacer un div que me muestre el contenido que quiero para ese id

Answer (score 2):

Es más simple de como lo estás imaginando. Generalmente para el tipo de cosas que piensas hacer no hace falta `return`. Lo que se suele hacer es alcanzar los elementos agrupados de una determinada manera usando selectores y asignarles una escucha (listener).

Imaginemos un `div` cuya clase es `ejercicio`, en jQuery podrás alcanzar todos los elementos `<a>`  con este selector:

```
.ejercicio a
```

Es importante comprender que el primer caracter significa el tipo de selector. En el caso del punto, significa que se selecciona por clase. Si fuese `#` indica que se selecciona por `id`, o si fuese `a` indica que se selecciona por el tipo de elemento, en este caso `a`, o `input`, `p`, `div`, etc.  En resumen, lo que indica `.ejercicio a` es *selecciona los elementos del tipo `a` que pertenezcan a la clase `ejercicio`*. Hay selectores muchos más complejos, que te permiten trabajar en escenarios complicados, agrupando elementos de diversas formas, pero no viene al caso hablar de eso ahora, pero es bueno que sepas que con los selectores puedes agrupar los elementos del DOM de cualquier forma que te interese.

En el código que sigue, seleccionamos los elementos con esa técnica, y al mismo tiempo escuchamos los clicks que ocurrirían en esos elementos, y dentro de la misma función mostramos el `href`. Generalmente con eso bastaría, no hace falta el `return`. Si hay que cambiar algo, lo haces dentro de esa misma función. Si de todos modos necesitas el dato para otra cosa, lo puedes asignar a una variable, pero esto generalmente no tiene mucho sentido.

```js
$(".ejercicio a").on('click', function(e) {
  //Esto evita la recarga de la página al hacer click
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ejercicio">
  <p>Estos son escuchados, haz clic en cualquiera de ellos y mira la consola</p>
  <a href="a1">a1</a>
  <a href="a2">a2</a>
  <a href="a3">a3</a>
</div>

<div class="otro">
  <p>Estos no son escuchados</p>
  <a href="#b1">b1</a>
  <a href="#b2">b2</a>
  <a href="#b3">b3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Como se asignaría a una variable? La variable que me devuelve es la ruta donde guardo el contenido que muestro. Mi idea era hacer un div con un contenido en su interior que muestra los archivos de una ruta, si el usuario clica en otro ejercicio cambiara la ruta del div ya que la quiero definir por la variable que me devuelve el jq. Y de esta forma podría mostrar los diferentes contenidos de cada ejercicio sin repetir código ni hace if/else. Busco la mayor eficiencia por encima de todo.

Comment: @Christianhidalgo no logro entender lo que quieres hacer. ¿Podrías por favor editar la pregunta y explicarlo mejor? De un buen entendimiento del contexto y de lo que quieres hacer dependerá siempre que te puedan aportar una respuesta óptima. Creo que al estar pendiente del `return` te estás confundiendo, quizá, como ya dije, no hace falta retornar nada.